# fetching problems with react useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

i got this error fetching data just for practice i don't wanna use JSON.stringfy i don't think will be good practice, solve it with details please thank you

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, episode_id, opening_crawl, director, producer, release_date, characters, planets, starships, vehicles, species, created, edited, url}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetching = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/films')
      const { results } = await response.json();
      const transformedData = results.map((el) => {
        return {
          id: el.episode_id,
          title: el.title,
          text: el.opening_crawl,
          date: el.releaseDate
        };
      });
      setData(transformedData);
    }
    fetching();
  })

  const outputedData = data.map((el) => {
    <div>
      <p>{el.id}</p>
      <p>{el.title}</p>
      <p>{el.text}</p>
      <p>{el.date}</p>
    </div>
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {outputedData}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


console.log(results)

6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {title: "A New Hope", episode_id: 4......}
```

Comment: How do you want to display it then? We can't really design your app for you!

Comment: array with objects

Comment: Also, I recommend adding a dependency array to your useEffect hook or you're going to trigger infinite fetches

Comment: done , so any solution ?

Comment: You can't just display an array with objects. You don't want it stringified, so do you want all the properties in each object on new lines, do you want it in a table, etc etc. Can you try something yourself first to give us some idea what you're going for?

Comment: data is an object and cannot be rendered as such in jsx, you need to interate over data.results using data.results.map and may be use <span>{{result.title}}</span> to check inside render function.

Comment: how about now ? it's just white screen , this is depressing

Comment: You have to return jsx form `outputedData` function which you are not doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace

```
const outputedData = data.map((el) => {
    <div>
      <p>{el.id}</p>
      <p>{el.title}</p>
      <p>{el.text}</p>
      <p>{el.date}</p>
    </div>
})
```

by

```
const outputedData = data.map((el) => (
    <div key={el.id}>
      <p>{el.id}</p>
      <p>{el.title}</p>
      <p>{el.text}</p>
      <p>{el.date}</p>
    </div>
))
```

Currently, your code doesn't return anything from the `map` function

Please note the use of the `key` attribute when displaying an array of React elements

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div className="App">
     {data.results.map((result) => {
       <span>{{result.title}}</span>
    })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display an array of non-React elements.
You need to do something like

```
return (
        <div className="App">
           {data.map(({title, episode_id, ...props}) => 
              <div>
                <span>{title}</span>
                <span>{episode_id}</span>
              </div>
           )}
        </div>
    );
```